# Обработка результатов парсинга html из одинаковых class

Tags: python, html, beautiful-soup

Всем привет!
Делаю парсер, в итоге нужно спарсить жанры для в файл csv (как идут последовательно, могут быть дубликаты).

Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get(URL)
print(page.status_code) #Проверка подключения
genres = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
genres = soup.findAll('span', class_='selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item')
print(genres)
```

Результат принта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Классы в коде сайта совпадают:
[image: Классы в коде сайта совпадают]

Не понимаю как можно с помощью BS4 оставить только жанр, т.к. на сайте class у страны и у жанра одинаковы полностью и дальше добавить в csv

Comment: Это ведь вывод из `bs4`? Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (кнопка [edit]), чтобы можно было поиграть. Я бы сначала сделал фильтрацию из парсера, чтобы страна не попадала в выборку, после разделение по `,` и готово

Comment: @gil9red, уменьшил пример. 
Да это из bs4. Не совсем понял как можно добавить фильтрацию из парсера, что бы страна не попадала в выборку class полностью совпадает

Comment: Для этого и нужен минимальный пример, чтобы я мог посмотреть что у вас происходит и что у того сайта, и, возможно, написать код так, чтобы работало :) А вообще, можно попробовать список оформить так, чтобы он вернул элементы через 1 раз, начиная со второго элемента, у вас ведь всегда сначала идет страна, потом жанр

Comment: Накидал алгоритм по вашему списку, но в следующий раз лучше вы подготовьте минимальный пример, а то неудобно работать с тем, что было, а такое может отпугнуть желающих помочь ;)

Comment: @gil9red Огромное Вам спасибо, буду пробовать. Вопрос теперь понял как формулировать

Comment: Пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @gil9red Принял, голосовать к сожалению нет могу по рейтингу(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположим, что у вас всегда теги чередуются: [`<страна>`, `<жанры>`, `<страна>`, `<жанры>`], тогда можно сделать так, чтобы получить новый начиная со второго элемента и с шагом 2 элемента.

Проверка алгоритма:

```py
items = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(items[1::2])
# [2, 4]
```

Проверяем на результате парсинга:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


items = ['<span class="selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item">США</span>', '<span class="selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item">мультфильм, фэнтези</span>', '<span class="selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item">США</span>', '<span class="selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item">мультфильм, комедия</span>']
items = [BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser') for x in items]

genres_els = items[1::2]
print(genres_els)
# [<span class="selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item">мультфильм, фэнтези</span>, <span class="selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item">мультфильм, комедия</span>]
```

Работает! Теперь нужно вытащить значения жанров из списка. Для этого перебираем список элементов-жанров, получаем его текст, делаем разделение по `', '`:

```py
genres = [el.get_text(strip=True).split(', ') for el in genres_els]
print(genres)
# [['мультфильм', 'фэнтези'], ['мультфильм', 'комедия']]
```

Если же это нужно в один список добавить, тогда (*оператор `+=` позволяет один список в другой распаковывать, аналогом будет функция `genres.extend(...)`*):

```py
genres = []
for el in genres_els:
    genres += el.get_text(strip=True).split(', ')
print(genres)
# ['мультфильм', 'фэнтези', 'мультфильм', 'комедия']
```

Для удаления дубликатов можно поместить в множество (*либо изначально `genres` сделать множеством*):

```py
genres = sorted(set(genres))
print(genres)
# ['комедия', 'мультфильм', 'фэнтези']
```

Comment: Почему - то строка items в ответе работает не так как при полном результате парсинга. При обрабатывании: items = [BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser') for x in items] на полном результате парсинга выдает ошибку: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Не могу понять почему..(

Comment: `items = [BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser') for x in items]` вам не нужно использовать, у вас уже есть список элементов с странами и жанрами, вот его и подставляйте в `genres_els = items[1::2]`, где `items` будет ваша переменная с списком элементов